# MacBook dropping Wi-Fi/network connection

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

Since purchasing this new MacBook, I have had the problem of my Wi-Fi intermittently not working. I will have a strong signal, be in the middle of working, and suddenly the page will not load, or I get the spinning beachball. I thought (and hoped) that when the new OS X (El Capitan) came out, the problem would be solved. It hasn't been.

I've figured out that if I turn Wi-Fi off, then immediately back on and then just reload the page, it will work fine. But that is just a band-aid; I want to get to the root of why this is happening. I know it is not an internet/network issue on my end as I just upgraded to a brand new router and modem, and upgraded to the fastest cable internet available. It only happens on the MacBook. Not the iPhone, not the iPads/iPods, not the printer.

I have run the diagnostics and taken a sample of all the times it happens to see if there is a common denominator, but there isn't. My network provider suggested moving the router closer to where I typically work so it need not go through too many walls, but it hasn't impacted the issue at all.

The only thing that has changed is that I have used the MacBook, adding applications, bookmarks, documents, etc. This was not an issue when I first got the laptop. It started about a month in.

In researching the issue, it is clear a lot of Mac users are having the same problem, but no "fix" that I have come across (and I have tried them all) has worked.

Any lifeline to fixing this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Just curious but where are you when this happens? Townhouse, apartment building? I had to go to a very strong router due to the fact that there were about 30 Verizon FIOS routers all blanketing my townhouse with their signals.

Once I upgraded to a high end Tri-Band wifi router, the issue cleared up when using the 5ghz connection and it's smooth sailing even two floors above the router location.

Comment: I'm in my house. It's 1 floor, open concept, and only ability 1200-1300 sqft. Modem/router is centrally located

Comment: Yeah that is strange then. I have a new MBP and haven't noticed any issues. It's up to date with the latest patches and whatnot. Only thing I can think of is that something is emitting enough of a signal that it is breaking up yours. One of my in-laws had a microwave that when running killed the wifi for the whole house which, frankly, terrified me when I visited.

Comment: It's up to date on everything. I don't really use my microwave very often. I've examined trends and nothing sticks out. All that seems clear is this is an OS X issue and not a network issue, since no other device is affected

Comment: Yeah, that's all I can think of. Have you tried it elsewhere? Someplace with free wifi like the library? That's the only other test I can think of. Maybe at the Apple store.